# How to model preference strength in Spark ALS with implicit feedback?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, spark-mllib

I am trying to use Spark MLib ALS with implicit feedback for collaborative filtering and I have two questions:

- according to [this](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf) paper it seems that I may need to provide both 0- and non-0 preference records wherein 0 means there's no user-product association while non-0 values represent association strength. I assume providing 0-preference records is not necessary in Spark but I would like to confirm it as I couldn't find any example of using Spark ALS with implicit feedback
- the 2nd question pertains to preference values. The paper cited above mentions log scaling as a possible approach and I was wondering if there are typical formulas being used